# JSON file is not served

Tags: 2010, json

In a standard team site, I have a document library that host a static website with html files as well json files loaded asynchronously with javascript.

This was working well in SharePoint 2007. unfortunately, since we migrated to SharePoint 2010, a http GET request on a JSON file fails with:

> An error occured while processing resource `/foo/bar.json`. 
>   The page must have a `<%@ webservice class="MyNamespace.MyClass" ... %>` directive.

This just doesn't make sense. I want the json file to be served as a plain-text resource.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I translated the error message from French to English myself. Please edit the question if you know how the genuine message.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, which web.config file I should modify? I just want to modify only for one site not for the whole server. Thanks in advance.
Raghu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good idea to disable the handler. In SharePoint 2013, some services like Managed Metada or Excel Services are relying on it and won't work anymore without it.

For example, when you open an Excel file in SharePoint using Excel services, the page calls some `.json` files when loading : 
`[myserver]/_vti_bin/DynamicGridContent.json/GetRangeContent`

Or when you want to select a value in a managed metadata field :
`[myserver]/_vti_bin/TaxonomyInternalService.json/ValidateTerms`

You can find the complete list of JSON used by SharePoint in the ISAPI folder :
[image]

So, instead of disabling the handler, you can filter the path to apply the handler only on files from the `/_vti_bin/` folder :

`<add name="JSONHandlerFactory" allowPathInfo="true" path="/_vti_bin/*.json" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />`

And so you will be able to store and call your own `.json` in a document library without impacting other features.

Comment: Note that I didn't recommend to disable the handler. Using a `path` filter sounds like a good workaround.

Comment: I can upload json files but can't edit when mapped to network drive.

Answer (score 1):

The default `web.config` contains in `<system.webServer><handlers>` this handler:

```
<add name="JSONHandlerFactory" path="*.json" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

As such, SharePoint thinks that URLs ending with `.json` are backed up by a web service.

I don't know whether native fonctionnalities rely on such services, hence I don't think it's a good idea to disable this handler. Apparently, Microsoft didn't think that the storage of JSON files in a document library is a valid use case.

Comment: Already added this string in web.config still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best practice but it worked for me: rename to `.TXT` and it will work as good.